# Getting awekward background by default when running android app from Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3?

Tags: android, background, android-edittext, android-spinner, android-studio-2.2

I developed one app in Android Studio 1.5. and then i saw new version of Android Studio which is 2.2 Preview 3.
I upgraded Android studio on system and reopen same project in that studio.it runs perfectly well, only the issue is now whenever i am running that project on device which have API Level <21 means lower than Lollipop. i am getting Awkward background in Edittext on every page. For example. Please see Screenshot which i attached.
[image: Screen1][image]

same issue i am also facing for some other widgets like, Spinner and dialogbox select.

what i have to do ?

Answer (score 1):

build.gradle:

```
  buildscript {

    .....

      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        .......    
      }
    }

    ......
```

change your project `build.gradle` as shown above. it will work.